# How can i seperate my fetch request to another file in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am using react and trying access the promise object which is defined in one file (service file) from another file (class component) .but when am importing the getData to another file ,it gives me undefined.
Can someone help me out in this.

```
service.js file
export const getData=()=>{
    fetch('url', {
                method:'Get',
            })
            .then(data=> {
             return   data.json()
            })
           
}

component file 
import {getData} from '../Service'
console.log(getData()) //gives undefine
```

Comment: `../Service` look like a typo

Comment: this is something like a mock code I have pasted , not the actual  code snippet. Please ignore the imports  it is working fine in real code .

Comment: Try to return the `fetch` function too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

component file

```
let getFetch = async () => {
   const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
   let res = await getRequestData(url);
   console.log(res)
}
getFetch();
```

service.js

```
const getRequestData = async (url) => {
    let resData = await fetch(url)
                        .then( res => res.json() )
                        .then( async (result) => {
                                                    return result
                                                } ,
                                    (error) => { 
                                                return error 
                                                });
    return resData;
}

export default getRequestData;
```

Comment: In this no need to add method in fetch api as GET method is by default if your request is GET else need to add
refer for more details  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

you should return data in  function getData

```
    service.js file
export const getData=()=>{
  return fetch('url', { // add return here
                method:'Get',
            })
            .then(data=> {
             return   data.json()
            })
           
}

component file 
import {getData} from '../Service'
console.log(getData()) //gives undefine
```